# React-Redux , state not updating correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, formik

I have a small invoicing app, that should show invoices on a list and be able to add new/edit old invoices also.

State is managed with `redux`, and binding is done with `React-redux`.

Everything is peachy until I try to call `useDispatch` hook with my form values. It dispatches the
correct values, but somewhere along the way to the reducer all data from the rows array disapper. All
the other data gets dispatched correctly.

My form values that gets sent to the reducer:

```
dispatch(newInvoice({
           "id": 4,
           "name": " xvsvsd",
           "street": "vsdvs",
           "zip": "sdfss",
           "city": "sefsd",
           "due_date": "2020-07-01",
           "rows": [
             {
               "quantity": 5,
               "currency": "eur",
               "unit_price": 3,
               "unit_of_measurement": "kpl",
               "vat": 4,
               "name": "test",
           },
           {
               "quantity": 4,
               "currency": "eur",
               "unit_price": 3,
               "unit_of_measurement": "kpl",
               "vat": 4,
               "name": "test1",

           }]
           
         }))
```

My action

```
export const newInvoice = (props) => {
    console.log(props)

    return {
        type: 'ADD_NEW',
        data: {
            
            id: props.id,
            name: props.name,
            street: props.street,
            zip: props.zip,
            city: props.city,
            due_date: props.due_date,
            rows: [
                {
                    quantity: props.rows.quantity,
                    currency: props.rows.currency,
                    unit_price: props.rows.unit_price,
                    unit_of_measurement: props.rows.unit_of_measurement,
                    vat: props.rows.vat,
                    name: props.rows.name,
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My reducer

```
const invoiceReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_NEW':
            console.log(state)
            console.log(action.data)
            return [...state, action.data  ]
    
      default:
        return state
    }
}
```

**Edit**
You asked for initialState, it is this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test company",
        "street": "Testikatu 1",
        "zip": "00100",
        "city": "Helsinki",
        "due_date": "2020-08-01",
        "rows": [
            {
                "quantity": 3,
                "currency": "EUR",
                "unit_price": 1.24,
                "unit_of_measurement": "kpl",
                "vat": 24,
                "name": "Sample invoice row 1"
            },
            {
                "quantity": -1,
                "currency": "EUR",
                "unit_price": 2.48,
                "unit_of_measurement": "kpl",
                "vat": 24,
                "name": "Sample invoice row 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Another test company",
        "street": "Testikatu 3",
        "zip": "00100",
        "city": "Helsinki",
        "due_date": "2020-08-05",
        "rows": [
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "currency": "EUR",
                "unit_price": 150,
                "unit_of_measurement": null,
                "vat": 0,
                "name": "Sample row"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I `console.log` the `action.data` it shows undefined on all the fields of the rows array.

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: what are you getting if you console.log action completely ?

Comment: what is `initialState` ?

Comment: `quantity: props.rows.quantity,` but `props.rows` is an array so `[].quantity` is undefined

Comment: @RedBaron I edited my post with initialState

Comment: @aravind_reddy 

Object
data:
city: "sefsd"
due_date: "2020-07-01"
id: 4
name: " xvsvsd"
rows: Array(1)
0:
currency: undefined
name: undefined
quantity: undefined
unit_of_measurement: undefined
unit_price: undefined
vat: undefined
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
street: "vsdvs"
zip: "sdfss"
__proto__: Object
type: "ADD_NEW"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Hey, row is an `array` so you should iterate over it in your `action` if you want to access objects properties; something like `rows: props.rows.map({...values}) => ({...values})`

Comment: @Aatu81 i have added the answer...

Comment: WTH your actionCreator is too complex? you are just returning the data which you receiving in function parameter. instead of 'props' => 'data' and return 
{ type: 'ADD_NEW', data }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try modifying your action like this

```
export const newInvoice = (props) => {
console.log(props)

return {
    type: 'ADD_NEW',
    data: {
        
        id: props.id,
        name: props.name,
        street: props.street,
        zip: props.zip,
        city: props.city,
        due_date: props.due_date,
        rows: props.rows.map(row => ({...row})
    }
}
}
```

because your rows is an array so if you try to access row without index directly it will give undefined

Comment: Thank you! Are you sure the syntax is correct on the rows: ?

I get a compiling error with it. 

For me it only seems to work with : 
rows: props.rows.map(row => ({ ...row }))

Comment: yeah oops sorry for the grammatical mistaked...update now..